# for loop in R not producing desired output

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse

In R, when I input the following code in the iris dataset:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(Petal.Width == 0.2 & Species == "setosa") %>% 
  dim()
```

I get

```
[1] 29  5
```

I would like to loop through values where Petal.Width = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 and get 5 different outputs.

```
list1 = list(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
for(i in list1){
  df_test <- iris %>% 
    filter(Petal.Width == i & Species == "setosa") %>% 
    dim()
}
df_test
```

However, the above code only returns one output:

```
[1] 1 5
```

Why is this happening and how can I get it to return 5 outputs instead?

Comment: you need to create an empty list and fill it at each iteration. It's better if you define the dimension first if you know it beforehand.

Comment: `l <- list()` outside the loop, then assign with `l[i] <-` inside.

Comment: `df_test`is modified at each iteration, you have only the last one in the end

Comment: @RLave Creating an empty list and filling it dynamically is possible but not very efficient. Better to use `map` (or `lapply`).

Comment: I agree, I was just pointing the errors. Also I suggested that is better to define the dimension of the output first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for an explicit `for` loop here; it's better to use `map` (or `lapply` in base R) instead

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list1, ~iris %>%
  filter(Petal.Width == .x & Species == "setosa") %>%
  dim())
#[[1]]
#[1] 5 5
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 29  5
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 7 5
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 7 5
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 1 5
```

The output object is a `list`.

---

In response to your comment, you could use a nested `map`

```
map(setNames(list1, list1), function(x) map(setNames(list2, list2), function(y) iris %>%
    filter(Petal.Width == x & Species == y) %>%
    dim()))
#$`0.1`
#$`0.1`$setosa
#[1] 5 5
#
#$`0.1`$versicolor
#[1] 0 5
#
#$`0.1`$virginica
#[1] 0 5
#
#
#$`0.2`
#$`0.2`$setosa
#[1] 29  5
#
#$`0.2`$versicolor
#[1] 0 5
#
#$`0.2`$virginica
#[1] 0 5
#
#
#$`0.3`
#$`0.3`$setosa
#[1] 7 5
#
#$`0.3`$versicolor
#[1] 0 5
#
#$`0.3`$virginica
#[1] 0 5
#
#
#$`0.4`
#$`0.4`$setosa
#[1] 7 5
#
#$`0.4`$versicolor
#[1] 0 5
#
#$`0.4`$virginica
#[1] 0 5
#
#
#$`0.5`
#$`0.5`$setosa
#[1] 1 5
#
#$`0.5`$versicolor
#[1] 0 5
#
#$`0.5`$virginica
#[1] 0 5
```

Comment: what can I do if I now want to also loop through list1 and all the Species values? In this case, I create `list2 = list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")`. I would be expecting 15 outputs, since I want all combinations of list1 and list2?

Comment: @wussyx I'd use a nested `map` approach, see my update. Then `flatten` the nested `list` as necessary.